# Number of real zeros of a polynomial $x^3+px+q$ (where $p$ and $q$ are real) in the real interval $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

This is a common type of problem in mathematics competitions. I was wondering if there exists a general solution, or at least a general strategy, to solve this type of problems. I can think of many different specific strategies I've used over the years, but what I want to know is if there exists a general method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finding the maxima and minima of this polynomial inside the interval $[a, b]$ should do the job.

Comment: So you want the roots of the polynomial?

Comment: Could you point me to some specific strategies and/or the problems they solve?

Answer (score 1):

The existence of stationary points $a_1$ and $a_2$ and the sign of $f(a_1)f(a_2)$ should tell you for an arbitrary interval.
(With the added fact that f is a cubic continuous function of course).
I'll propose a theorem (which I'm not sure if there exists a name for it or not).

$$\text{Let} \quad f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} \quad \text{be a cubic polynomial and let} \quad a_1, a_2 \quad \text{be stationary points (if they exist)}. \\ \text{Then} \quad f \quad \text{has} \\ \text{one zero if} \quad f \quad \text{has no stationary points or has two stationary points such that} \quad f(a_1)f(a_2) > 0 \\ \text{two repeated zeroes and one other zero if} \quad f \quad \text{has two stationary points such that} \quad f(a_1)f(a_2) = 0 \\ \text{three DISTINCT roots if} \quad f \quad \text{has two stationary points such that} \quad f(a_1)f(a_2) < 0$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that Sturm's theorem will do what you want.